# Shaka player m3u8 Videos are playing fine on Chrome browser but not playing on Safari browser

Tags: reactjs, m3u8, gorilla, shaka

We are using shaka player 4.3.5 version and mux.js plugin to play normal m3u8 (non drm) videos. It works perfectly on chrome but on Safari browser it fails.
Sample code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-zv5wcw?file=src%2FApp.js

Please suggest any solution wihtout changing the player and video format.

Tried mux js plugin with latest versions